# imagepolygon(), How to make the lines thicker?

Tags: php, gd

Is it possible to make the lines generated with imagepolygon() to be thicker? Also, can you get a "higher resolution"? I get quite alot of visible pixels when the line curves.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepolygon.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the thickness by using the [`imagesetthickness`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesetthickness.php) function.

```
imagesetthickness($img, 5);
imagepolygon($img, array(5, 5, 60, 80, 10, 50), 3, $color);
```

[(example)](http://codepad.viper-7.com/sJoRdR)